# How to display all table row contents of my database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image, tablerow

I'm trying to do a shopping gallery. I managed to display my database table's first row content (content includes: image thumbnail of product, product name and product price). now i'm trying to display my table's second row content. how do i do this? when i try it, PHP still shows all of the first row's contents.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="Dress1"> 
   <a href="Prod1.php"><img id="Image1" src="../imgs/thumb/<?=$imgsml?>"></a> 
   <p id="ProductCodeText"> 
   <?php echo $prd_name;?><br/>Price: <?php echo $price; ?> &nbsp;Php</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Dress2"> 
    <a href="Prod2.php"><img id="Image1" src="../imgs/thumb/<?=$imgsml?>"></a> 
    <p id="ProductCodeText"> 
    <?php echo $prd_name;?><br/>Price: <?php echo $price; ?> &nbsp;Php</p> 
    </div>
```

then Dress3 and 4

PHP CODE:

```
<?php  include_once("../incs/dbcon.php"); 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$prd_id = $_REQUEST["prd_id"];
$sub_id = $_REQUEST["sub_id"];
$prd_name = $_REQUEST["prd_name"];
$descr = $_REQUEST["descr"];
$price = $_REQUEST["price"];
$sizes = $_REQUEST["sizes"];
/*$imgsml = $_REQUEST["imgsml"];
$imgbig = $_REQUEST["imgbig"];*/
$featured = $_REQUEST["featured"];
$prd_status = $_REQUEST["prd_status"];
$colors = $_REQUEST["colors"];
$prd_code = $_REQUEST["prd_code"];
$date_release = $_REQUEST["date_release"];
$stk_status = $_REQUEST["stk_status"];
$ctr_id = $_REQUEST["ctr_id"];
$price_sale = $_REQUEST["price_sale"];
$onsale = $_REQUEST["onsale"];
$mostPopular = $_REQUEST["mostPopular"];
$mn = $_REQUEST["mn"];
$year = $_REQUEST["year"];
$imagewidth = $_REQUEST["imagewidth"];
$newArrival = $_REQUEST["newArrival"];
$cat_name = $_REQUEST["cat_name"];
$sub_name = $_REQUEST["sub_name"];

if (isset($_POST['prd_id'])) $prd_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prd_id']);
    if (isset($_POST['sub_id'])) $sub_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sub_id']);
    if (isset($_POST['prd_name'])) $prd_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prd_name']);
    if (isset($_POST['descr'])) $descr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descr']);
    if (isset($_POST['price'])) $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    if (isset($_POST['sizes'])) $sizes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sizes']);
    if (isset($_POST['imgsml'])) $imgsml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imgsml']);
    if (isset($_POST['imgbig'])) $imgbig = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imgbig']);  
    if (isset($_POST['featured'])) $featured = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['featured']);
    if (isset($_POST['prd_status'])) $prd_status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prd_status']);
    if (isset($_POST['colors'])) $colors = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['colors']);
    if (isset($_POST['prd_code'])) $prd_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prd_code']);
    if (isset($_POST['date_release'])) $date_release = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date_release']);    
    if (isset($_POST['stk_status'])) $stk_status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stk_status']);
    if (isset($_POST['ctr_id'])) $ctr_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ctr_id']);  
    if (isset($_POST['price_sale'])) $price_sale = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price_sale']);  
    if (isset($_POST['onsale'])) $onsale = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['onsale']);          
    if (isset($_POST['mostPopular'])) $mostPopular = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mostPopular']);
    if (isset($_POST['mn'])) $mn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mn']);
    if (isset($_POST['year'])) $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
    if (isset($_POST['imagewidth'])) $imagewidth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imagewidth']);
    if (isset($_POST['newArrival'])) $newArrival = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newArrival']);
    if (isset($_POST['cat_name'])) $cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']);
    if (isset($_POST['sub_name'])) $sub_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sub_name']);
}

$szQuery = "SELECT * FROM products";
$rs = mysql_query($szQuery) or die(mysql_error()."<br>$szQuery");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
$prd_id = $row->prd_id; 
$sub_id = $row->sub_id; 
$prd_name = $row->prd_name;
$descr = $row->descr;
$price = $row->price;
$sizes = $row->sizes;
$imgsml = $row->imgsml;
$imgbig = $row->imgbig;
$featured = $row->featured;
$prd_status = $row->prd_status;
$colors = $row->colors;
$prd_code = $row->prd_code; 
$date_release = $row->date_release; 
$stk_status = $row->stk_status;
$ctr_id = $row->ctr_id;
$price_sale = $row->price_sale;
$onsale = $row->onsale;     
$mostPopular = $row->mostPopular;
$mn = $row->mn;
$year = $row->year;
$imagewidth = $row->imagewidth;
$newArrival = $row->newArrival;
$cat_name = $row->cat_name;
$sub_name = $row->sub_name;
}
?>
```

as much as possible i need someone who's willing to teach me step-by step and patiently. oh, and yes, i'm new at MySQL and PHP.

Comment: I think the problem is with your array fetching...

Comment: You must use the loops to iterate through rows from a query from a database. The very same query to the database should include all necessary lines, not just one.

Comment: Can U try <div> instead of table ?

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. Have a look at this example

```
<?php
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elternplaner");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td align='center'>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
                </td>
                <td align="center"><a href="edit.php?iId=<?php print($row['iId']); ?>" ><img src="edit.png" width=30px title="Edit"></a>&nbsp;<a href="delete.php?iId=<?php print($row['iId']); ?>"><img src="delete.png" title="Delete" width=30px></a></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['vName']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['eGender']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['dBirthDate']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['vEmail']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['iPhoneNo']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['vLocation']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['dtLastLoginDate']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['dtMemberSince']) ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php print($row['eStatus']) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

This will return the entire table

Comment: HTML CODE:
    <div id="Dress1">
    <a href="Prod1.php"><img id="Image1" src="../imgs/thumb/<?=$imgsml?>"></a>
    <p id="ProductCodeText"> <?php echo $prd_name;?><br/>Price: 
    <?php echo $price; ?> &nbsp;Php</p>
    </div><!--end of Dress1-->


    <div id="Dress2">
    <a href="Prod2.php"><img id="Image1" src="../imgs/thumb/<?=$imgsml?>"></a>
    <p id="ProductCodeText"> <?php echo $prd_name;?><br/>Price: 
    <?php echo $price; ?> &nbsp;Php</p>
    </div><!--end of Dress2-->

then Dress3 and Dress4

Comment: I don't think that you displayed the first row from your database. coz i didn't find any mysql query.. Frankly,i didn't get your problem

Comment: yes. i have a database. i think you need the PHP code as well. i'm gonna post it as well then.

Comment: This is happening because you are not looping your html code. The `echo $price` or whatever is giving only the first value. Inorder to get next row of the table,you have to loop it

Comment: or else directly echo the data in your controller file(PHP Code where you assign `$price = $row->price;`). But,looping your "view" file is recommended

Comment: oh, i see. how do i loop it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code should be something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ......."
$resultset = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

now you can iterate through $rows array using loop.